# How to get greatest Date record and multiply to that dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, case, greatest-n-per-group

Hello Everyone I want to get greatest Date record and multiply to that dynamically below is sample structure of my table and here is DB fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cde3fdc07915a2e8c23195be646c5a20

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------+
| ID  | Sequence Id |   Date    | Amount |   Frequency    |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------+
| 123 |           1 | 01-Jan-20 |     50 | Monthly        |
| 123 |           2 | 01-Feb-20 |     50 | Monthly        |
| 123 |           3 | 01-Mar-20 |    150 | Monthly        |
| 123 |           4 | 01-Apr-20 |    200 | Monthly        |
| 123 |           5 | 01-May-20 |    510 | Monthly        |
| 123 |           1 | 01-Jan-20 |    510 | Quarterly      |
| 123 |           2 | 01-Apr-20 |    300 | Quarterly      |
| 123 |           1 | 01-Jan-20 |    600 | Semi-Annually  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------+
```

I want to retrieve data dynamically with the help of filter and want to multiply amount according to Frequency. **Get greatest record  according to Date and multiply amount with 12 if frequency monthly or multiply 4 if frequency Quarterly or multiply 2 if frequency Semi-Annually**

```
Ex. 1. If we run query select ID, Rent from Table where Date is greater than or equal 01-jan-2020 and less than or equal to 01-may-2020 and frequency equal to Monthly then out put should be like below -
 +-----+-------------+
 | ID  |        Rent |
 +-----+-------------+
 | 123 |       6,120 |
 +-----+-------------+ 

2. If we run query select ID,Rent from Table where Date is greater than or equal 01-jan-2020 and less than or equal to 01-may-2020 and frequency equal to Quarterly then out put should be like below -
 +-----+-------------+
 | ID  |        Rent |
 +-----+-------------+
 | 123 |        1200 |
 +-----+-------------+ 
3. If we run query select ID,Rent from Table where Date is greater than or equal 01-jan-2020 and less than or equal to 01-may-2020 and frequency equal to Semi-Annually then out put should be like below -
 +-----+-------------+
 | ID  |        Rent |
 +-----+-------------+
 | 123 |        1200 |
 +-----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this over multiple ids and frequencies at once, then you can use `row_number()` like so:

```
select id,
    amount * case frequency
        when 'Monthly'       then 12
        when 'Quaterly'      then 4
        when 'Semi-Annually' then 2
    end as rent
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id, frequency order by StartDate desc) rn
    from table1 t
    where StartDate between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-05-01' and frequency = 'Monthly'
) t
where rn = 1
```